# Min numpy - 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I get confused by this example.

```
A = np.random.random((6, 4, 5))
A
A.min(axis=0)
A.min(axis=1)
A.min(axis=2)
```

What mins are we really computing here?

I know I can think of this array as a `6x5x4` Parallelepiped in 3D space and I know `A.min(axis=0)` means **we go along the 0-th axis**. OK, but as we go along that 0-th axis all we get is 6 "layers" which are basically rectangles of size `4x5` filled with numbers. So what min am I computing when saying `A.min(axis=0)` for example?!?! I am just trying to visualize it in my head.

From `A.min(axis=0)` I get back a 4x5 2D matrix. Why? Shouldn't I get just 6 values in a 1D array. I am walking along the 0-th axis so shouldn't I get 6 values back - one value for each of these 4x5 rectangles?

I always find this notation confusing and just don't get it, sorry.

Comment: Try with one dimension less, unique numbers, and draw it for yourself. That may help clarify things.

Comment: No, I want 3 dimensions, one dimension less doesn't help. I seem to understand the things there.

Comment: For axis=0: there are 4x5 "sets" of 6 numbers. `A.min(axis=0)` will calculate the minimum of each of those sets, and you end up with 4x5 numbers. Which is what you get back.

Comment: small example can help, e.g. use `A = np.random.random((2, 1, 3))`

Comment: @9769953 But then "walking along the 0-th axis" is not the right way to think of this operation. In fact we are walking on the 4x5 side of the parallelogram and we look "up" (let's say up), and we see 4x5 (i.e. 20) stacks of height 6. So for each of these stacks of height 6 is where we apply the min function. So we get back 4x5 numbers in a 2D 4x5 array. Is that the right way to think of it? Is there a good visual tutorial on these matters somewhere? The doc just says "Return the minimum of an array or minimum along an axis."

Comment: Your analogy seems to be correct. But: perhaps you shouldn't try to think about it in a geometrical fashion. After all, NumPy is just about manipulating numbers array-wise. (As a slightly weird example, if you want the mean across every 3rd value in an array, you could reshape it to 2D, with shape (-1, 3), then compute the mean along axis 1, then flatten the result. Just manipulation, no geometric figures involved.)

Comment: @9769953 Hm :) You confused me even more now. Thanks anyway. I don't know. I will think some more on it.

Comment: Another example: your brain might start to melt if you try to picture all the ways you can use `np.einsum()` (I know mine will; I rather stick to the more mathematical method of handling tensors).

Comment: `A.min(axis=0)` is equivalent to do a paire-wise reduction of `[A[i, :, :] for i in range(A.shape[0])]` using the function `np.minimum`. Put is differently, for the axis (1,2), each of the 4x5 pencils of length 6 are being reduced to a unique number (by computing the minimum of 6-values for each pencil). Visually, the axis 0 is the one that is compacted/smashed (others are left untouched).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yeah, thanks. I was thinking of it the same way after 9769953's first few comments.

Answer (score 3):

You calculate the min across one particular axis when you are interested in maintaining the structure of the remainder axes.

The gif below may help to understand.
In this example, your result will have shape (3, 2).
That's because you are getting the smallest value along axis 0, which squeezes that dimension into only 1 value, so we don't need the dimension anymore.

[image]

Comment: Haha, thanks. I just did it in Power Point here for you!